# new distinct list by removing a object from a List which has duplicate elements for different objects

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

How to remove the objects from the list if that list has unique objects with same elements?

```
static class UserDTO {

        private String name;
        private String email;

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

    }

        UserDTO u1 = new UserDTO();
        u1.setEmail("alex@gmail.com");
        u1.setName("one");

        UserDTO u2 = new UserDTO();
        u2.setEmail("andy@gmail.com");
        u2.setName("two");

        UserDTO u3 = new UserDTO();
        u3.setEmail("andy@gmail.com");
        u3.setName("three");

        UserDTO u4 = new UserDTO();
        u4.setEmail("ankit@gmail.com");
        u4.setName("four");


        UserDTO u5 = new UserDTO();
        u5.setEmail("amar@gmail.com");
        u5.setName("five");

        List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>(); 
        users.add(u1);
        users.add(u2);
        users.add(u3);
        users.add(u4);
        users.add(u5);
```

Now how to sort or filter this users list to new List which has only u1,u2,u4,u5 because u2,u3 has same email.

I tried using  all these options
1)

```
List<UserDTO> newUsersList =    uers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

2)

```
List<UserDTO> newUsersList =  users.stream().filter(o-> ! o.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase(users.parallelStream().findAny().get().getEmail())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

3)

```
 List<UserDTO> newUsersList =  users2.stream().filter(o-> users2.stream().map(UserDTO::getEmail).anyMatch(p -> !p.equalsIgnoreCase(o.getEmail()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

4)

```
Set<UserDTO> newUsersList = users2.stream().filter(o-> users2.stream().map(UserDTO::getEmail).anyMatch(p -> !p.equalsIgnoreCase(o.getEmail()))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I want the

```
List<UserDTO> newUsersList = new ArrayList<>(); 

for(UserDTO u :newUsersList ) {
    System.out.println(u.getName() + "  "+u.getEmail());
}
```

printing

```
one  alex@gmail.com
two  andy@gmail.com
four  ankit@gmail.com
five  amar@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can override `hashCode` and `equals`, follow Ravindra Ranwala's instructions and use a `Set`:

```
    Collection<UserDTO> unique = new HashSet<>(users);
```

If you cannot override them, you can use `TreeSet` and provide it with a custom `Comparator`:

```
    Collection<UserDTO> unique = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(UserDTO::getEmail));
    unique.addAll(users);
```

While very simple, these approaches have the downside of losing the order of elements. If this is important, try removing the duplicates from a `List` "manually":

```
    Collection<String> uniqueEmails = new HashSet<>();
    users.removeIf(user -> !uniqueEmails.add(user.getEmail()));
```

You can also use this approach for a `filter` stage in a `Stream`:

```
    users.stream()
         .filter(user -> uniqueEmails.add(user.getEmail()))
         ...
```

As you can see with this approach or with Eran's answer, pure stream based solutions are not simple. They have to either rely on outside state or create temporary collections/mappings to achieve the filtering. It becomes a lot simpler when implementing `hashCode`/`equals`.

Comment: I think the last approach here is the simplest with the fewest number of side-effects (like overriding methods or losing the order of elements).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collectors.groupingBy` to group the `UserDTO` instances by email address, and then grab the first instance of each group:

```
List<UserDTO> newUsersList =
    users.stream() // Stream<UserDTO>
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserDTO::getEmail)) // Map<String,List<UserDTO>>
         .values() // Collection<List<UserDTO>>
         .stream() // Stream<List<UserDTO>>
         .map(list -> list.get(0)) // Stream<UserDTO>
         .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<UserDTO> that has one instance for each
                                        // unique email
```

The `users.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList())` attempt would only work if you implement `equals` of `UserDTO` class to compare only the email address (which means two instances having the same email will be considered equal).